# Unresolved node modules dependency using Webpack and System

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, systemjs

I have the following **ES6** import in my code to import a project dependency from the `node_modules` folder:

```
import React from 'react';
```

By using this webpack configuration, everything works as expected:

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel',
        test: /(\.js|\.jsx)/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I end up with a bundled file containing the react dependency that has been automatically added.

But if I configure babel to use `modules: 'system'` to output imports as `System.register`:

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel',
        test: /(\.js|\.jsx)/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        query: {
          modules: 'system',
          moduleIds: true,
          keepModuleIdExtensions: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

then the bundled file does not contain anymore the react dependency and I have to append the `systemjs` library to the compiled file after going through webpack.

How are we suppose to handle this configuration using `webpack`? why can't `webpack` bundle the react dependency using `system` as it already does when compiling into `commonjs`?

PS: I am specifically asking to achieve this using `webpack`, not `systemjs-builder` or `jspm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how Webpack works. Webpack can handle AMD and CommonJS modules, it cannot handle SystemJS modules.

For Webpack to support a module system, it needs to be able to look at the JS and statically decide what files depend on what, and then modify the file so that it will work and be compatible with other modules. It doesn't now what SystemJS is, so all it sees is a JS file that doesn't reference any CommonJS modules because it never uses `require()`.

Comment: I understand technically why this is happening. But if System is supposed to be the next standard, I would have thought that Webpack could have extended its System support (even if it's an extra configuration) so that if an import is undefined it looks in the `node_modules` as it does with commonjs ...

Comment: That would be a question to ask the maintainer of Webpack. System is still pretty new. There has also been a "webpack 2.x" in the works for a while. Perhaps that will support it. `SystemJS` is based on a spec that is still changing a ton. Saying "it will be the next spec" assumes that the spec isn't still being developed, which it is.

Comment: If you are using webpack though, there isn't really anything to be gained from using a module system other than ES6 -> CommonJS. Webpack 2 will support standard ES6 modules, so then you'll just want to disable module transpiling in Babel entirely.